# How do I make text scroll in a single line on a video using FFmpeg without using an additional line?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ffmpeg

**How do I make text scroll in a single line on a video using FFmpeg without using an additional line?**

*make text scroll in a single line on a video using FFmpeg on Android, but text shows other lines*
My code

```
     downloadProgressDialog.show()

outputPath =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path + "/$fileName.mp4"

        var videoPath = videoPath!!
        var text = bottomTextScroll!!
        var fontPath = fontPath!!
 
        val query = ffmpegQueryExtension.addScrollingTextToVideo(
            videoPath,
            text,
            fontPath,
            outputPath!!

        )
        CallBackOfQuery().callQuery(query, object : FFmpegCallBack {

            override fun success() {
                downloadProgressDialog.clearProgress()
                downloadProgressDialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Video Download Success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                )
                    .show()
                var notificationText = "Your video has been successfully downloaded."
                showNotification(notificationText)


                var i = Intent(this@MainActivity, VideoShareActivity::class.java)
                i.putExtra("outputPath", outputPath)
                startActivity(i)
                finish()


            }

            override fun cancel() {
                downloadProgressDialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Video Download Cancel",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                )
                    .show()
            }

            override fun failed() {
                downloadProgressDialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Video Download Fail",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()

                var notificationText = "Your video download Fail."
                showNotification(notificationText)
            }

            //get video download progress
            override fun updateProgress(progress: Int) {
                val duration = getVideoDuration(videoPath!!)  // get video duration

                downloadProgressDialog.updateProgress(progress, duration)
            }

        })
```

```
fun addScrollingTextToVideo(
    videoPath: String,
    text: String,
    fontPath: String,
    outputPath: String
): Array<String> {
    val inputs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    val scrollSpeed = 5
    val textSize = 40

    inputs.apply {
        add("-i")
        add(videoPath)
        add("-vf")
        add("drawtext=fontfile=$fontPath:text='$text':fontsize=$textSize:fontcolor=white:x=w-(mod($scrollSpeed*n\\,w+tw)):y=h-text_h-105")
        add("-c:a")
        add("copy")
        add(outputPath)
    }

    return inputs.toArray(arrayOfNulls(inputs.size))
}
```

***make long text scroll in a single line on a video using FFmpeg on Android, but text shows other lines in***

please give me the solution

Comment: Identifying which library are you using along with an image/set of images showing the output may help others figure out what what is going on.

Comment: I use this library:-

   implementation("com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.4")

Answer (score 1):

error soul complete
below is my code work text show single line

```
    fun addScrollingTextToVideo(
    videoPath: String,
    text: String,
    fontPath: String,
    outputPath: String
): Array<String> {
    val inputs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    val scrollSpeed = 5
    val textSize = 40
    val cleanedText = text.replace("\n", " ")
    inputs.apply {
        add("-i")
        add(videoPath)
        add("-vf")
        add("drawtext=fontfile=$fontPath:text='$cleanedText':fontsize=$textSize:fontcolor=white:x=w-(mod($scrollSpeed*n\\,w+tw)):y=h-text_h-105")
        add("-c:a")
        add("copy")
        add(outputPath)
    }

    return inputs.toArray(arrayOfNulls(inputs.size))
}
```